# Even after injection of http, Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following simple code but I get the error even though $http is injected:

```
angular.module('bizapp')
.controller('SalesCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', GetSalesInvoices]);

function GetSalesInvoices($scope, $http) {
    $scope.invoices = [];
    $scope.refresh = function($scope, $http) {
        var url = "https://foo.ic/api/salesinvoice/SalesInvoices";
        $http.get(url)
          .success(function(data) {
            $scope.invoices = data.d.results;
          })
          .error(function(){
              console.log('opss')
          })
          .finally(function() {
           $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
         });
    }
}
```

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have `$scope` and `$http` in your controller, so you do not need to pass them as arguments to function `refresh`. Change

```
$scope.refresh = function($scope, $http) {
```

to

```
$scope.refresh = function() {
```

and it should all be working

Comment: A closure (refresh in this case) is an inner function that has access to the outer (controller in this case) function's variables .